# load 70 Billion records in teradata

Tags: sql, database, database-performance, teradata

**Issue**
Hi all I have arounf 7 files each having 7000 million records each and 1 have to laod them in 4 tables in teradata .
I dont have any constraint and i am using Teradata Parallel Transpoter
my Load is Full Refresh and I am using Informatica.

I am getting of throughput of around 45000Rows/sec .

**Requirement**
Can anyone suugest any way to improve performance in informatica, or by partitioning in table.
I have 6 columns in table and all are composite keys.

Comment: Can you give us more inside on the physics? How many nodes has your Teradata? What's the bandwidth between the informatica and teradata? Have you tried TPT directly to see if infomatica, the network or some parameters are the bottleneck. How much bytes do one record have?

Comment: We also need the DDL of the tables including the Primary Index. And what TPT loader is used?

Answer (score 0):

couple of Generic observations :

1: See if you can change tier setting in informatica workflow manager.
2:Use fast load connection in Informatica if possible.